# What is the best way to stub date in spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using Rails 5.2.2.1 and Rspec. 
Please, how can I stub time to always have this test green?

*Few edit I added Timecop as suggested and updated my question but it is still failing*

Today my test fails because it's the first day of the month...

```
  before(:each) do
    Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2019, 03, 31, 12, 0, 0))
  end

  let(:date_from) { Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2019, 03, 26, 12, 0, 0)) }
  let(:date_to)   { Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2019, 03, 31, 12, 0, 0)) }

  subject { Dashboard.new(date_from: @date_from, date_to: @date_to) }
describe "#sales_by_week" do 
    it "returns the  number of sales by week" do
        create(:sale, created_at: 2.weeks.ago)
        create(:sale, created_at: 3.days.ago)
        create(:sale, created_at: Date.today )

        res = subject.sales_by_week

        expect(res.values.last).to eq(2)
    end
end

describe "#sales_by_month" do 
        it "returns the number of sales by month" do
            create(:sale, created_at: 2.day.ago)
            create(:sale, created_at: 1.day.ago)

            res = subject.sales_by_month

            expect(res.values.last).to eq(2)
        end
    end
```

Here are the method I am testing:

```
class Dashboard
    attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

    def initialize(params)
        params ||= {}
        @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from],Time.now.beginning_of_month.to_date.to_s)
        @date_to   = parsed_date(params[:date_to], (Date.today + 1).to_s)
    end

    def sales_by_week
      Sale.group_by_week(:created_at, range: (@date_from..@date_to),time_zone: "Paris", week_start: :mon).count
    end

    def sales_by_month
      Sale.group_by_month(:created_at, range: (@date_from..@date_to),time_zone: "Paris", week_start: :mon).count
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop):
It provides very simple way to `freeze` time at any point you want, for example:

```
describe "#sales_by_week" do
 before { Timecop.freeze(Time.now.beginning_of_week+6.days) }

 it "returns the  number of sale by week" do
  create(:sale, created_at: 2.weeks.ago)
  create(:sale, created_at: 3.days.ago)
  create(:sale, created_at: Date.today )

  res = subject.sales_by_week

  expect(res.values.last).to eq(2)
 end
end
```

Comment: thanks for helping I updated my question, I added Timecop but it is still failing :(